# Send 2 different emails based on 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying out Apps Script and want my code to send an email based whether a condition is True or False. I was able to execute and receive an email when the only conditional is True but I'm quite unsure how to add the else statement as seen below as an error sign appears once I save the script

```js
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues();
  var paticipateTicket = rData[0][1];
  var ticketType = rData[0][2];
  var ticketNumber = rData[0][14];
  var company = rData[0][3];
  var name = rData[0][4];
  var email = rData[0][5];
  var remarks = rData[0][1];


  if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "Yes") return;{
     var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is confirmed with ticket number ${ticketNumber}. <p>See you at the tournament at the details below.</p>
  Your ticket number is ${ticketNumber} with a ticket type of  and you'll be participating under ${company} </p><p><img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI" width = "200 px" length = "300 px"></p>`;
  var msg = name + "Your payment has been verified. Your ticket number is " + ticketNumber + ".Participating under " + company
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg, { htmlBody: html });
  }

  else (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "No") return;{
  var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is has been paused and here’s why: </p> <p> ${remarks}</p>
  
  var msg1 = name + "Your payment has been paused. Below is the reason why”
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg, { htmlBody: html });
}  

}
```

Comment: participateTicket and remarks are both equal to rData[0][1]

Answer (score 1):

There were some missing characters and in one case the wrong " symbol was used, try replacing the if-else block with this:

```
if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "Yes"){
    var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is confirmed with ticket number ${ticketNumber}. <p>See you at the tournament at the details below.</p>
  Your ticket number is ${ticketNumber} with a ticket type of  and you'll be participating under ${company} </p><p><img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI" width = "200 px" length = "300 px"></p>`;
    var msg = name + "Your payment has been verified. Your ticket number is " + ticketNumber + ".Participating under " + company
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg, { htmlBody: html });

  } else if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "No"){
    var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is has been paused and here’s why: </p> <p> ${remarks}</p>`
    var msg1 = name + "Your payment has been paused. Below is the reason why";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg1, { htmlBody: html });

}
```

Google Apps Script view after updating the code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I am now able to save the code.  Although when I type in "no" to trigger the else message, I'm still receiving the message for those that are in "yes"

Comment: @Lyrien ARe you aware that the the if-statements in the code are case-sensitive? (it's not the same to type `Yes` than `yes`, `No` than `no`.

Comment: @Rubén Yes I'm aware of that.  But problem still stands unfortunately.

Comment: @Lyrien Could you clarify the conditions? I can update my answer as needed but at the moment I understand that you want to send the first email if: You're typing `Yes` on any cell other than 17, and the second email when you're typing `No` on any cell other than 17, is that right?

Comment: Hi Bryan. Column 17 is where the conditions are (Yes/No). So based on what I typed in that column, it should send the email corresponding to it.

Comment: @Lyrien Another problem in the if-statement expressions is the use of the boolean operator. The code is using the O operator (`||`) while apparently the AND operator (`&&`) should be used. This the initial problem was solved thanks to the above answer, please post a new question including a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const [, paticipateTicket, ticketType, company, name, email, , , , , , , , , ticketNumber] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 15).getValues()[0];
  if (e.range.columnStart == 17 && e.value == "Yes") {
    var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is confirmed with ticket number ${ticketNumber}. <p>See you at the tournament at the details below.</p>
  Your ticket number is ${ticketNumber} with a ticket type of  and you'll be participating under ${company} </p><p><img src = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nMiIfUgfFPYn4YOzXmEwJlaiNRPyOHsI" width = "200 px" length = "300 px"></p>`;
    var msg = name + "Your payment has been verified. Your ticket number is " + ticketNumber + ".Participating under " + company
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg, { htmlBody: html });

  } else if (e.range.columnStart == 17 && e.value == "No") {
    var html = `<h2> Hello ${name} !</h2><p>Your purchase of a ${paticipateTicket} under ${company} is has been paused and here’s why: </p> <p> ${remarks}</p>`;
    var msg1 = name + "Your payment has been paused. Below is the reason why";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "2022 Charity Golf Tournament", msg1, { htmlBody: html });
  }
}
```

remarks is undefined

Comment: It's working unfortunately, I now received both yes and no messages

Comment: try it again...

Comment: Hi! I tried this again and I only now receive messages for YES instead of no